# Distributed Transactions: .NET Framework vs .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-core, msdtc

I have the following code sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TransactionManager.DistributedTransactionStarted += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Promoted to distributed transaction!");
    };
​
    const string connectionString = @"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Integrated Security=true;";
​
    using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
    using (var conn1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var conn2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn1.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("conn1 opened");
​
        conn2.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("conn2 opened");
​
        tx.Complete();
    }
​
    Console.ReadLine();
​
}
```

When executing this code in a .NET Framework (4.8) Console Application (against SQL Server Express 2017) it yields the following output:

[image: Output of code in .NET Framework Console]

Since the transaction is being promoted to a Distributed Transaction, I expect a similar Console Application targeting .NET Core (3.0) to throw a

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException (*This platform does not support distributed transactions.*).

However, the actual output is:

[image: Output of code in .NET Core Console]

Why is this? I expect the promotion of a transaction to a distributed transaction to be framework-agnostic.

---

*Edit:* This .NET Core (3.0) code sample does something with the database connections:

Database Schema:

```
CREATE DATABASE [TestDB1] 
GO
CREATE TABLE [TestDB1].[dbo].[Table]([Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL)
```

.NET Core (3.0) Console Application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TransactionManager.DistributedTransactionStarted += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Promoted to distributed transaction!");
    };

    const string connectionString = @"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB1;Integrated Security=true;";

    using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
    using (var conn1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var conn2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn1.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("conn1 opened");
        using (var cmd1 = conn1.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] ([Value]) VALUES ('test 1')";
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("Record inserted through conn1");
        }

        conn2.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("conn2 opened");
        using (var cmd2 = conn2.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] ([Value]) VALUES ('test 1')";
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("Record inserted through conn2");
        }

        tx.Complete();
        Console.WriteLine("Transaction completed");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And the Console output:

[image: .NET Core Console output when doing something with the connections]

*Note:* This sample also succeeds when using 2 *different* connectionstrings for the 2 connections!

Comment: Try to actually do something from the connections.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this -- not on .NET Core 3, not on 3.1, not with `System.Data.SqlClient`, not with `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`. All variations produce an exception.

Comment: Does [transactionscope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netcore-3.1) *introduced in .Net Core 2.0* cover your use-case? Have a look at its [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netcore-3.1#examples).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NET Core **doesn't** support Distributed Transactions because it would require a different transaction manager on each platform. 
You can find more about this issue on https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/715.

This feature seems to be added to Release 5.0 from .NET Due by November 30, 2020

There is another thread [SA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328832/transactionscope-throwing-exception-this-platform-does-not-support-distributed-t) talking about this problem.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So why does @chrisv fail to get an exception?

Answer (score 1):

Distributed Transactions support was merged 3 hours ago for modern .NET
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/72051

Comment: Does this mean that distributed transaction work in .net core. Because as far as I can see for .net core 7 not .net core 5. Has anyon tested this?

Comment: The support is [Windows-only, and is a largely a straight port of C++ code to C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#distributed-transactions).