# how TransactionScope work with multi-threads

Tags: c#, transactionscope

Hi firstly thank you for your attention on this question；
Is there any way to implement a transaction like this in c#

```
using （Transactionscope x=new Transactionscope ())
{

   Thead A()=> Independent Transactionscope()  A（Insert into table X ）

   Thead B()=> Independent Transactionscope()  B（Insert into table Y ）

   Thead C()=> Independent Transactionscope()  C（Insert into table Z ）

   Thread.WaitAll(A,B,C)

  commit big transaction x/ rollback big transaction x
}
```

Comment: SQL commands that execute within a transaction must all execute against the same SQL connection. Therefore it makes no sense to separate them into threads;  there are going to get executed in series anyway.

Comment: @JohnWu on .Net Framework, TransactionScope can be used to initiate Distributed Transactions via MS DTC, so there is no need for all commands to be associated with the same Sql Connection. In fact, TransactionScope can be used for other ACID resources, such as queues or transactional file systems.

Comment: @StuartLC Interesting, and clever. It didn't occur to me to tie in MSDTC. Question: If OP were to do that for (sub)transactions in the same database instance, wouldn't there be potential for the threads to deadlock each other?

Comment: @JohnWu yes, DTC can lead to a lot of locking related issues and often reduce the scalability of an enterprise. Seemingly nowadays most folk prefer looking at compensated transactions, or moving the source of truth out of RDMS into events and commands (Actor Model,Event Sourcing and such)

Answer (score 2):

Note that Distributed Transactions are currently [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56332021) on .Net Core, only on .Net Framework.

In order to use a `TransactionScope` to span multiple threads, you'll need to use [DependentClone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.dependenttransaction?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) to tie the threads into the parent `TransactionScope`.

The steps are:

1. Start a `TransactionScope` on your main / first thread
2. Just before creating each thread, use `DependentClone` to create a `DependentTransaction`, and then pass this `DependentTransaction` instance to the new thread.
3. On the child thread, you can use the `TransactionScope(DependentTransaction)` constructor overload to create a linked `TransactionScope`, in which the child thread can perform local transactions.
4. As the work on each child thread is completed successfully, then commit both the thread `TransactionScope` and the `DependentTransaction`
5. On the main thread, wait until all threads are complete, and then commit the root `TransactionScope`

There's some caveats too:

1. Using `DependentTransaction` on multiple threads will immediately require the use of MSDTC.
2. Using multiple threads under a large DTC transaction isn't going to make insertion into the same table any quicker (Use `SqlBulkCopy` for that), and you'll want to measure whether parallel inserts into different tables, same database under a DTC transaction warrants the locking overhead or returns any performance benefit.
3. If you're using `async`, then you'll need [TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17527759)

More about [Transction Scope here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22512547/314291)

Comment: Great! Thx your guideline~

Comment: I would generally advise against DTC if possible, e.g. if you are doing a lot of connected work on the same database, then I would advise to use a Single Transaction - either use SqlTransaction on a single connection, or if using Transaction Scope with multiple (connection pool) connections, make sure that you close each connection before continuing the next one - this will typically wind up on the Lightweight Transaction manager.

Comment: On a single database, your time is usually better spent looking at optimising the performance on a single thread / doing the work sequentially, rather than trying to parallelize the work under an umbrella transaction.

Comment: `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption` is more for async / await purposes, since the continuation, and the final TransactionScope complete + disposal may be executed on a different thread than the one the TS started on. I have a suspicion however that async calls must complete sequentially, i.e. trying to parallelize async code (e.g. `Task.WhenAll`) will probably require the same handling as `DependentTransaction`, since the continuations could complete concurrently on different threads.